# How to publish php website under GNU GPL, but keep MySQL password?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some website, and I am planning register/login using MySQL for it. My website is licensed under GNU GPLv3.

Is there some way to let users see source code, but to still have the database safe (e.g. keep the php file with MySQL password unpublished)? I really want to share my code, but I don't want to somebody stealing data from my db.

My website isn't e-bank or something, but it can still contain sensitive data.

I am sorry for the license question, but I searched stackexchange for an hour and couldn't find a better place to ask

Comment: Just make a source archive, e.g. a `.tar.gz` tarball of (only) the source code and make it downloadable, or put the code on `github`

Comment: I don't understand the issue, just strip the credentials before distributing it?

Comment: Ummm.... what does this have to do with licensing anyway?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yes, I have gitorious account, my source code is here - I just didn't start making the passwords part

Comment: @chronodekar I am asking if it is legal - because according to GNU GPL, you have to share the source code, so I ask, if it is legal to don't share the php file with passwords.

Comment: Putting passwords in source code is always a bad idea (passwords should be configurable). And the GPL requires you to give source code only when you distribute your program, not when you are deploying it on a single server. See also the AGPL license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is *your* original code, you are free to choose which part to distribute under GPL. Also, if you configure and set up the code on a webserver, you are not distributing a modified version in the terms of the GPL.

The actual solution then is really simple: don't include the credentials in the distributed code.

Have a look at [how Wordpress does it](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php): they include a `wp-config-sample.php` file, which includes most settings with sane default values. But the database connection is empty. Users just copy this example to `wp-config.php` and add their needed values for the database connection.

Answer (score 1):

Thats why most of the OpenSource Websites use config file or separate PHP to set passwords.

Comment: So I can have a passwords.php file on my server and I am not required to put it out on gitorious?

Comment: @user1080431 that is correct. Have you seen any "passwords" for major OSS projects? NO. It's because that is an implementation detail and not required to edit the source code. See also Basile Starynkevitch's comment above.

Comment: Or simply remove your password and will it with placeholder in your code.